# Prevent iPhone Zooming On Certain Parts of Website?

Tags: html, css

I have a sticky header menu on the website I'm working on.  It contains a logo on the left side and menu options on the right side.  But I'm having a problem with iPhone zooming.

I do want users to be able to zoom into the page with their iPhone, but I don't want it to effect the size of the menu.  Right now when people zoom in, the menu options on the right start moving over to the left until they bump down to the next line (outside the menu bar).

Is there any way to do prevent zooming just for the menu bar, but allow it for everything else?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of HTML that you're using for your menu?

Comment: This isn't a scale/zoom issue...it's the structure / css of the menu that needs adjusting to make it responsive.

Comment: I agree with Paulie too. Are you using em or rem sizings at all?